# How to show leave expiry date of an employee

Tags: php, mysqli

First I count the number of days between leave dates and resume date e.g. From `26–July-2019` To `31-July-2019` is 5 days. Then I need to know the number of days counting from the leave date to the current date and store in a variable named `$count_days`.  if the no of leave days minus count_days is equal zero then I would say your leave has expired.

I could not figure it out how to get it right

```php
<?php

// include the file that defines (contains) the username and password
require_once("includes/mysqlconn.php");

// build qry
$qry = "SELECT employee.emp_num,employee.emp_lname,employee.emp_fname,eleave.leave_date,eleave.resume_date from employee INNER JOIN eleave ON employee.emp_num = eleave.emp_num where employee.emp_num = '".$_SESSION['empno']."'";

$records = mysqli_query($dbconn,$qry) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbconn));


$time_current =  time();

while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{

    $leavedate = strtotime($line['leave_date']);
    $resume_date = strtotime($line['resume_date']);
    //count days between dates to get no of leave days
    $leave_days  = ceil(abs($resume_date - $leavedate) / 86400);
    //this is to get days difference between no of leave days and the current day
    //when echo $count_days give me -1564264800 I don't know what this value stand for
    $count_days  = $leavedate - strtotime($time_current);


    if (($leave_days-$count_days) <> 0){

        echo "enjoy your leave";
    }else{

        echo "your leave has expired";
    }

}
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `$time_current` is already in *'time'* (integer) format, so `strtotime($time_current)` is probably NOT what you want to do. Second, if you are checking whether `resume_time` has passed (aka their leave is over), all you have to do is:

```
if( $time_current < $leave_time ){
    echo 'your leave has not started';
}elseif( $time_current > $resume_time ){
    echo 'your leave has expired';
}else{
    echo 'enjoy your leave';
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to know the number of days between, correctly subtract (already integer) `$time_current` and `$resume_date` and divide by 86400. For the sake of ease (and understanding) I have wrapped this into a function for you:

```
function numDaysBetweenTimes(int $time1, int $time2 = null) : int{
    if( !$time2 ){
        $time2 = time();
    }

    return ceil(abs($time1 - $time2) / 86400);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$line['leave_date'] = '2019-01-15 00:00:00';
$line['resume_date'] = '2019-01-05 00:00:00';

$time_current = time();
$leaveTime = strtotime($line['leave_date']);
$resumeTime = strtotime($line['resume_date']);

echo numDaysBetweenTimes($leaveTime, $resumeTime) . ' leave days<br/>';
echo numDaysBetweenTimes($resumeTime) . ' days between leave and now<br/>';
```

Output:

```
4 leave days
202 days between leave and now
```